# Can you submit the blog post here first before posting?

Tags: discussion, blog

I say this only because the otherwise excellent [Know Your RAM](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/know-your-ram/) post has a few grammar errors. By posting here first, you can get these corrected first, via comments, (or by making the post CW).

[**note**] I could have left this as a Comment, but it taints the post a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I post I usually hang around in chat after and then make any corrections that are brought to my attention.

Personally, posting in meta first doesn't appeal to me that much, but I will happily take any corrections on content or grammar in comments on the blog, here, or in the [Server Fault Comms chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127).

Just keep in mind that if you take it to the extent of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2153/should-kyle-be-corrected-and-if-he-doesnt-why I will just get confused :-P

Comment: Great. I didn't think of chat.

Comment: I'm above average on the grammar-Nazi scale, but those guys are crazy.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'd go back and edit a post anywhere based on that site but in some ways its the most interesting SE site to me. I mean I find computers interesting and all but its an area that is in my comfort zone and tends to have very defined answers, whereas the discussions on language are fascinating.

Comment: the person who posted that item clearly didn't go to school the same place I did. Your grammar was not incorrect, nor was it ambiguous or confusing in the slightest to those of us who actually speak the language, as opposed to those who know only the theory. Kind of like the difference between those of us who do sysadmin work and somebody fresh out of school with a bunch of certificates but doesn't know the front of a server from the back.