# rss feed for the serverfault blog double posts

Tags: support, blog

The Server Fault blog RSS feed always comes up twice in Google reader (with different timestamps)...The stackoverflow blog rss doesn't do this...anyone else have this problem?

From my screenshot, this began happening on the 9th of december...My first guess is that this is just google reader being weird...

This is the feed url from google reader: http://blog.serverfault.com/rss

[image]

**Edit following Zoredache's answer**
Showing that the body is different...
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [rss feed for serverfault blog full post like SO](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1126/rss-feed-for-serverfault-blog-full-post-like-so)

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7425/various-wordpress-feeds-for-same-blog -- The /feed is the canonical uri for the feed that has the full content and doesn't double post. Will try to redirect when I find out the proper way to handle this.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, and good use of the wordpress site! you should probably answer this question as using the /feed url is exactly what i was after...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have seen this in other feeds occasionally as well.  It appears to be a 'feature' of Google reader.  If I understand it correctly, it appears that if an item in the feed is modified you will see both the original version and the updated version as separate items.

You can even see it if you look at the two RRD posts, they have a different timestamp, and if you open them you will see slightly different body.

So the simple fix would be for Kyle/George to never make any errors and post a perfect version the first time.  :p

Comment: Also see: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1102/can-you-submit-the-blog-post-here-first-before-posting

Answer (score 1):

The RSS reader in Opera isn't having this problem.

Comment: I'm presuming at this stage that it is google reader...