# rss feed for serverfault blog full post like SO

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, blog

Using the same image from [my other question](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1121/rss-feed-for-the-serverfault-blog-double-posts) about the serverfault blog

Can the rss feed have the full post, the same as the stackoverflow blog rss?

[image]

Comment: It's on my todo to fix this ... there are a couple of other issues that I need to address first that take priority

Answer (score 3):

Kyle's response to [my other question about the rss feed](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1121/rss-feed-for-the-serverfault-blog-double-posts) answers this question...Simply use the /feed URL instead of /rss...I presume when you press the little "star" in Firefox etc that it must default to /rss which is why it got picked up in the first place.

Full SF blog feed URL: http://blog.serverfault.com/feed/

Comment: They need to put a big RSS icon linking to the correct URL at the top of the blog.  I was close to just unsubscribing. :)